# Why are the results of the two expressions different?

Tags: c#, mysql

MySQL Expression One:

```
string userName = InputUser.Text.ToString().Trim();
string judgeStr = "select * from users where username='"+userName+"'";
```

MySQL Expression Two:

```
string userName = InputUser.Text.ToString().Trim();

string judgeStr = "select * from users where username='@username'";  
judgeCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
```

The result shouldn't be same?

Comment: are you getting different results? AddWithValue does the implicit conversion of string to varchar in your case.

Comment: Don't put quotes around parameters.  Doing that means you are literally comparing to "@username" and not the value you set the paramter to.  It's like expecting `int i = 2; string s = "i";` to result in `s` being "2" instead of "i".

Comment: Yep,got it!Many Thanks!!!!!!!!@juharr

Comment: Yes,the same results!@SushilMate